# Variables in where clause

Tags: sql

Is there any way to create where condition with the variable you created? Like;

```
 select id,
      case when yid='2024' then '2023-24'
            when yid='2023' then '2022-23'
   end as year,
      case when yid='7830' then '044'
           when yid='7888 then '040'
  and as course
from table
 where  year=@year and course=@course;
```

So this is not right, but another way to accomplish i need

Comment: Assuming the unclosed literal for 2024 was just a typo and fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the expression to avoid repeating it:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select id,
        case when yid='2024' then '2023-24'
             when yid='2023' then '2022-23'
          end as year
    from table
)
WHERE year=@year;
```

... **BUT** ...

You will get **much** better performance if you make the effort to match the `@year` variable to the column, rather than the other way around. As requested, any indexes on the `yid` column are **worthless** for this query, and you're forcing the database to compute the case expression for *every row in the table*, even those you don't need.

If you can add some code before the query to mutate an incoming `2023-24` in the `@year` variable to instead match `2024` value already stored in `yid`, you will be able to match with an index and avoid extra per-row computations. *The query could be multiple orders of magnitude faster.*

You didn't share which DB you're using, so the string manipulation might be a little different depending on what you have, but for SQL Server that could look like this:

```
SET @year = LEFT(@year, 2) + RIGHT(@year, 2);

SELECT id,
   case when yid='2024' then '2023-24'
        when yid='2023' then '2022-23'
     end as year
FROM table
WHERE yid=@year;
```

Comment: i have one more value to search like that. its like;   case when cid='7180' then '044' when cid='7800' then '045' en as course. how can i make this 'set' at the top?